How to set source control Azure App Service (WebApp) with Azure .SDK .NET
In Blazor, I have set up the creation of a Resource Group, Azure App Service, Hosting Plan, KeyVault..., using Azure SDK for .NET.
When creating the Azure App Service, I also want to deploy a web app along with its code, but I'm facing an issue.
The client is a registered app with permissions to create resources on the Azure portal. I've established a connection using ClientSecretCredential
and can create all resources on the Azure Portal without any issues.
However, I'm unable to add source control for the WebApp to enable deployment.
This is error
Service request failed. Status: 400 (Bad Request) Content: {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Parameter x-ms-client-principal-name is null or empty.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Parameter x-ms-client-principal-name is null or empty."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"51011","MessageTemplate":"Parameter {0} is null or empty.","Parameters":["x-ms-client-principal-name"],"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Parameter x-ms-client-principal-name is null or empty."}}],"Innererror":null} Headers: Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED X-AspNet-Version: REDACTED X-Powered-By: REDACTED x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes: REDACTED x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-global-writes: REDACTED x-ms-request-id: fcfe9625-328b-4407-8a60-7ef7c8ac853a x-ms-correlation-request-id: REDACTED x-ms-routing-request-id: REDACTED X-Content-Type-Options: REDACTED X-Cache: REDACTED X-MSEdge-Ref: REDACTED Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2024 07:08:39 GMT Content-Length: 447 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1

if (client != null)
{
    var webAppResourceId = WebSiteResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscription!.Data.SubscriptionId, _resourceGroupName, _appServiceName);
    WebSiteResource webAppResource = await client.GetWebSiteResource(webAppResourceId).GetAsync();
    var sourceControl = await webAppResource.GetWebSiteSourceControl().GetAsync();

    switch (_optionBuildProvider)
    {
        case "GitHubActions":
            siteSourceControlData = new SiteSourceControlData
            {
                RepoUri = new Uri(_repoUri),
                Branch = _branch,
                IsManualIntegration = false,
                IsMercurial = false,
                IsDeploymentRollbackEnabled = true,
                IsGitHubAction = true,
            };
            break;

        case "AppServiceBuildService":
            siteSourceControlData = new SiteSourceControlData
            {
                RepoUri = new Uri(_repoUri),
                Branch = _branch,
                IsManualIntegration = false,
                IsMercurial = false,
                IsDeploymentRollbackEnabled = true,
                IsGitHubAction = false,
            };
            break;

        case "AzurePipelines":
            break;
    }

    if (siteSourceControlData != null)
    {

        ArmOperation<WebSiteSourceControlResource> operation = await sourceControl.Value.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, siteSourceControlData, cancellationToken);

        if (operation.HasCompleted)
        {
            _customerPortal!.TemplateState = TemplateStateType.Finish;
            await UpdateCustomerPortalAsync(_customerPortal);
            _deploySourceControlExist = true;
        }
    }
}

I need a solution to add source control programmatically
